# Moodle let user change his own picture

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme, moodle-boost

Im working on a moodle new theme and I want to let user change his picture from his profile page what should I do?

I overide the profile page then I tried to make it but i think it will need a new php file?

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: try to check here : https://docs.moodle.org/2x/pl/User_pictures
and also check the the files in moodledirectory/user/profile
It'd be interesting to see how you overwritted the profile page.

Comment: I tried but still not working 

Comment: Can you tell us what isn't working? Do you get an error message?

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/User_pictures#Updating_user_pictures